# Load partial view as modal on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So I'm trying to load, after I click on a button, a partial view from controller, containing a bootstrap modal.

I'm not sure where the problem is, but when I click the button the first time, the DOM is added, but modal is not shown. The second time I click, the modal is shown for <1s and then I only get that gray modal-background.

My button

```html
"<button class='btn btn-info edit-category' onclick='showModal()' data-category-id='" + full.id + "'>Edit</button>"
```

My `showModal`-function:

```js
function showModal(){
    $("#div1").load("/Category/EditCategory");
    $("#createCategory").modal();
}
```

My Partial-View-Action:

```cs
public ActionResult EditCategory()
{
    return PartialView("Admin/_CategoryAdd", new CategoryDetailModel{Title = "Test"});
}
```

Part of my PartialView "_CategoryAdd":

```html
@model CategoryDetailModel

<div class="modal" id="createCategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Category"
                  data-ajax="true"
                  data-ajax-method="POST"
                  data-ajax-mode="replace"
                  data-ajax-failure="failed"
                  data-ajax-success="success">
```

funny thing is, when I do NOT click the button and enter both lines in browser-console, it works as expected.
When I execute the method in console, it's the same as clicking the button.

I also thought, maybe it's a time thing, so I added `setTimeout` with 5000ms but didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: @freedomn-m it says, done is not a function :D the #div1 is in the main-html, a few lines under the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @freedomn-m I found that I can add a function, when load is done:

```js
$("#div1").load("/Category/EditCategory", 
    function(){$("#createCategory").modal('toggle');});
```

now it works